# Angular and Flexbox issues on some navigators

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

Im struggling with one bug with flexbox.

I developed a e-learning site with Angular using a very nice template from ThemeForest called Treo (https://treo.pulsethemes.com/angular/)

You can see this theme works perfectly on all devices and navigators. Because im not a professional web developer (currently specialized as ios developer) i avoided to touch css clases. Most of the pages i build were directly on top of the demo components. Of course i started from the "starter" project and just copied the components i wanted.

So, the problem came when i tried on different devices. It works fine on Google Chrome and Firefox, but when it comes to Safari and iOs devices (i didnt have Android) the layout didnt expands.

On Chrome and Firefox the content can be scrollable as expected, but on Safari and iOs, the wrapper class "wraps" (ironically) the content and didnt allow to scroll. I tried to check manually if there are different code but there are no extra CSS classes different. Just different navigation, modules, guards and the logic behind the app, not differences from the layout itself

Here are the two different versions i got:

Expected result (in Chrome but Firefox works fine too):
https://pasteboard.co/JrGwd0D.png

Result i got on Safari and iOs devices:
https://pasteboard.co/JrGxp1c.png

Check the bottom of the page. On Chrome and Firefox the content expands and there is a scrollable content, on Safari it shows the footer and wraps the content.

Its very annoying and im not sure why this is happening, i tried to add flexbox specific classes like webkit-flex and tried to change overflow to scrollable and similar workarounds, but they are patches that didnt solve the main issue.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT: SOME CODE**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<treo-vertical-navigation class="bg-cool-gray-900 theme-dark"
                     *ngIf="isScreenSmall"
                     [appearance]="'classic'"
                     [mode]="'over'"
                     [name]="'mainNavigation'"
                     [navigation]="data.navigation.default"
                     [opened]="false">

<div treoVerticalNavigationContentHeader>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="assets/images/logo/entrenador-on-dark.png">
    </div>
</div>

</treo-vertical-navigation>
```

```
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">

    <!-- Top bar -->
    <div class="top-bar theme-dark">

        <div class="container">

            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="logo"
                 *ngIf="!isScreenSmall">
                <img src="assets/images/logo/entrenador-on-dark.png">
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation toggle button -->
            <button class="navigation-toggle-button"
                    *ngIf="isScreenSmall"
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="toggleNavigation('mainNavigation')">
                <mat-icon [svgIcon]="'menu'"></mat-icon>
            </button>

            <!-- Spacer -->
            <div class="spacer"></div>

            <!-- Search -->
            <!-- <search [appearance]="'bar'"></search> -->

            <!-- Shortcuts -->
            <!-- <shortcuts [shortcuts]="data.shortcuts"></shortcuts> -->

            <!-- Messages -->
            <!-- <messages [messages]="data.messages"></messages> -->

            <!-- Notifications -->
            <!-- <notifications [notifications]="data.notifications"></notifications> -->

            <!-- User -->
            <user [user]="data.user"></user>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bottom bar -->
    <div class="bottom-bar"
         *ngIf="!isScreenSmall">

        <div class="container">

            <treo-horizontal-navigation [name]="'mainNavigation'"
                                       [navigation]="data.navigation.horizontal"></treo-horizontal-navigation>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- Content -->
<div class="content">

    <!-- *ngIf="true" hack is required here for router-outlet to work correctly. Otherwise,
         it won't register the changes on the layout and won't update the view. -->
    <router-outlet *ngIf="true"></router-outlet>

</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<!-- <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; {{currentYear}}
    </div>
</div> -->
```

I commented some of the lines because i dont want them to show actually on the code.

**Important CSS Classes**

```
> @import 'treo';

 enterprise-layout {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 100%;

    > treo-vertical-navigation {

        .treo-vertical-navigation-content-header {

            .logo {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                height: 80px;
                min-height: 80px;
                max-height: 80px;
                padding: 24px 32px 0 32px;

                img {
                    max-width: 200px;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    > .wrapper {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        min-width: 0;

        > .header {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 144px;
            max-height: 144px;
            min-height: 144px;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 49;

            @include treo-breakpoint('lt-md') {
                height: 80px;
                max-height: 80px;
                min-height: 80px;
            }

            @include treo-breakpoint('xs') {
                height: 64px;
                max-height: 64px;
                min-height: 64px;
            }

            .top-bar,
            .bottom-bar {
                display: flex;
                flex: 1 1 auto;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .top-bar {

                .container {
                    height: 80px;
                    max-height: 80px;
                    min-height: 80px;

                    @include treo-breakpoint('xs') {
                        height: 64px;
                        max-height: 64px;
                        min-height: 64px;
                    }
                }
            }

            .bottom-bar {

                .container {
                    height: 64px;
                    max-height: 64px;
                    min-height: 64px;
                }
            }

            .container {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                position: relative;
                max-width: 1440px;
                width: calc(100% - 64px);
                margin: 0 32px;

                @include treo-breakpoint('lt-md') {
                    width: calc(100% - 32px);
                    margin: 0 16px;
                }

                .logo {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;

                    img {
                        width: 160px;
                        min-width: 160px;
                        max-width: 160px;
                    }
                }

                .navigation-toggle-button {
                    margin-right: 8px;
                }

                .spacer {
                    display: flex;
                    flex: 1 1 auto;
                    height: 1px;
                }

                search {
                    margin-right: 8px;
                }

                shortcuts {
                    margin-right: 8px;
                }

                messages {
                    margin-right: 8px;
                }

                notifications {
                    margin-right: 8px;
                }

                treo-horizontal-navigation {
                    margin-left: -16px;
                }
            }
        }

        > .content {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            max-width: 1440px;
            width: calc(100% - 64px);
            margin: 32px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            overflow: hidden;
            @include treo-elevation('lg');

            @include treo-breakpoint('lt-md') {
                width: calc(100% - 48px);
                margin: 24px;
            }

            @include treo-breakpoint('xs') {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
            }

            > *:not(router-outlet) {
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                flex: 1 1 auto;
            }
        }

        > .footer {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
            max-height: 80px;
            min-height: 80px;
            z-index: 49;

            @include treo-breakpoint('xs') {
                height: 56px;
                max-height: 56px;
                min-height: 56px;
            }

            .container {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                position: relative;
                max-width: 1440px;
                width: calc(100% - 64px);
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0 32px;

                @include treo-breakpoint('xs') {
                    width: calc(100% - 32px);
                    margin: 0 24px;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &.fixed-header {

        > .wrapper {

            > .header {
                position: sticky;
                top: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    &.fixed-footer {

        > .wrapper {

            > .footer {
                position: sticky;
                bottom: 0;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is very hard to say without any _actual_ code. My best guess is flex-attributes (flex: <value>) or some wrapping (flex-wrap) or justifying (justify-contet or align-items) awry. But these are just shots in the dark without any code.

Comment: check on https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/ maybe there is a bug. But I guess that's just a very common side effect of using fancy "best experience" frameworks. `flex` has many side effects. For every tag or property you can check browser support - ask google "can i use ..." and there is a service caniuse.com - avoid not fully supported.

Comment: I updated the post with the main HTML files wich wraps the router outlet.

Components didnt have any css that can cause the problem, so it should be on the main "structure" class

Also i tried on an android device and worked fine. So the issue remains on Safari and iOs devices